# Dynamic Style Change Method Fails

Tags: javascript

Attempting a dynamic style change below, but the function falls silent. I've used JSHint, and all seems fine.

```
function styleInput(elClass,color)
{
  "use strict";

  var document;
  elClass = document.getElementsByClassName(elClass);



var len = elClass.length;

    for (var i=0; i < len;i++) {

        if (elClass[i].className === elClass) 


                {

                  var tmp = elClass[i];


                  tmp.style.backgroundColor = color;

                  tmp = " ";





                }

        }




}

styleInput("fm_bushido", "#f3f3f3");
```

-----HTML-----

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="fm_bushido txt" placeholder="Name:"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the variable `elClass` twice and overwriting the value passed into the function with that returned from `document.getElementsByClassName(elClass);`. Once your script gets down to `if (elClass[i].className === elClass)`, you're comparing the classname of the element with the element itself, **not** the value you passed into the function (`fm_bushido`).

Just change one of those elements' names and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, starting a FormClass for dynamically creating forms, nothing unique, simply an OOP Code example. Could you suggest a tut on passing class names in "classname classname" format. Getting what is either before or after the space?

Comment: If you can, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)...it will make your like a lot easier